# What do you call a member of a staff at a university?

Tags: single-word-requests

A faculty may consist of professors; then, what does a staff consist of?

For example, I want to know which noun can refer to a member of the staff in this [cs.toronto.edu staff list](http://web.cs.toronto.edu/people/staff.htm#Administrative%20Staff), with job titles like

- Administrative & Financial Assistant
- Administrative & Financial Assistant - AI
- Administrative HR Assistant
- Financial Assistant
- Financial Officer
- Graduate Assistant
- Graduate Program Administrator
- Graduate Program Assistant
- Technical Staff - CDF Supervisor
- Technical Staff - CSLab
- Undergraduate Assistant

and many more.

Comment: In many places outside North America, most faculties certainly do not consist of [professors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor#The_United_Kingdom.2C_Ireland_and_other_English_speaking_countries)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you would simply say "staff members". If you are referring to a specific cateogry of staff, you might say "administrators" or "janitors" or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Following Jay, "staff member" sounds good.  I have also heard "staffer."  You could consider just "employee," though that would not exclude members of the faculty.

It is also common, in my experience, to use the noun "staff" as a plural to mean "members of the staff" ("faculty" can get a similar treatment).  For example, "Staff are entitled to a discount on football tickets."

Comment: Quite true. I'm upvoting you even though you're a competing answer. :-)